# Push Notification, is it possible to get the push notification to slide down even when the app is open?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

is it possible for the push notification to slide down from the top of the phone when the app is open just like it would if it's minimised? Right now I'm trying to replicate this behaviour using :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

        //restore push
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appRestorePush" object:nil];



}
```

and responding to the notification by animating my own custom UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. The approach you're taking is correct, you need to implement and animate your own view.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. That's slightly annoying. Do you know of anywhere I can find the exact specs of the view, colour etc?

Comment: I don't, but I also wouldn't try to exactly match it - you don't know when Apple will change it. I'd expressly choose a different UI that matches the internal app UI.